# Adding newline based on 'find character' and go back to first space

Tags: excel, pdf, newline, data-cleaning

I'm working on cleaning a ton of data that has a common pattern like this:

REG#: 15082608 Date:15-JUN-15 BACKTRACK Cleared: Date:31-AUG-15 Recvd:13-MAY-15 Agency:OAKLAND (and about 25 other data points for each record but, following this pattern). A raw PDF file with a bunch of records is here: http://abc.ca.gov/reports/Actions2015/ActionsFinal_09-23-15.pdf

I'm not a programmer but, have tried Refine and a bunch of Excel tests but, haven't found a way I can do this for a large number of records (thousands but, will start with dozens :).  So, my question is:

Could a script identify the colon ':' and then go backwards to the first space before that colon eg   'Date:15-JUN-15 BACKTRACK Cleared: Date:31-AUG-15' and enter a new line for each instance? So the resulting output would be:

```
Date:15-JUN-15 BACKTRACK 
Cleared: 
Date:31-AUG-15
```

The other question is that I can manually copy and paste each record (of all 25+ data points) into a unique cell but, what would be ideal is that I save the PDF as a spreadsheet and it basically builds a row for every row it finds - meaning in some cells there would be multiple colons and I would need the script to bump down the other rows accordingly.

Once I get to that place I can do a text-to-column and then build my database from there.

Comment: Given the static nature of the labels it might be easier to create an `Array("Status:", "Date:", "Dist:", ...)` and loop through while replacing each var with `vbCrLf&var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the cells containing the data and run this short macro:

```
Sub FixData()
   Dim r As Range, v As String, vOut As String
   For Each r In Selection
      v = r.Text
      vOut = ""
      If v <> "" Then
         ary = Split(v, " ")
         For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            If InStr(1, ary(i), ":") > 0 Then
               vOut = vOut & vbCrLf & ary(i)
            Else
               vOut = vOut & " " & ary(i)
            End If
         Next i
         r.Value = vOut
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]